# GraphQL performing INSERTs on cache_discovery table

Tags: 8

We have a drupal site which acts as GraphQL API endpoint and during heavy loads (about 17 graphql requests/sec), our site seems to go down and the bottleneck appears to be GraphQL doing a lot of INSERTs to the cache_discovery table.

Does anyone know if this is a drupal core feature or can we disable this just for graphql?

Thanks

Comment: From core.api.php: "discovery: Contains cached discovery data for things such as plugins, views_data, or YAML discovered data such as library info." So this is not a normal core behavior when you run a discovery process that often.

Comment: @4k4 thanks for the details.  We are constantly making a route('path') graphql call which returns the full markup of a page, but to build the page, it involves other views/plugins.  Could that be why each time graphql is called it tries to perform an INSERT to the discovery table?  Thanks!

Comment: No, using a plugin doesn't do this. Discovering is done when installing the module which contains the plugin. There are also some config or content changes which can trigger a discovery process, for example when you modify blocks. But those changes should not happen in production in regular requests.

Comment: Hmm, would a cron job triggers discovery?  That's one other strange behavior I noticed.  It would try to trigger a cron job on a graphql request.

Comment: This depends on what you are doing in the cron job. Under heavy load you shouldn't run cron from a request, schedule a cron job.